# Typescript Modules vs Object Literals

Tags: typescript, module

I have some methods, that in my API I want them to be exported as grouped.

I was wondering what's the guideline about this, personally I'd go for `module` but some of my work pals say it's old school, which I kinda don't agree.

**Option 1**

utils.ts

```
export function foo() {
    return;
}
```

public-api.ts

```
import * as utils from "./utils";

export {
    utils
}
```

**Options 2**

```
export module utils {
    export function foo() {
        return;
    }
}
`
```

For me i'd go for option 2, it requires less boilerplating and I don't believe it's obsolete. If it is I cannot find any doc supporting this.

I wonder what are the guidelines especially if there is any TS collaborator that can answer this.

Thanks